# Asp.net Getting error while saving username to string based column in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

**Scenerio**

I've a role rights page in my web application. In this page I've a dropdown and a gridview when I select any role from a dropdown its selected index event was run and get the below datatable from SQL Server.

**Store Procedure**

Below is the store procedure if Role Rights not assign before then `ELSE` condition runs and from there I'll get null values in column `Prepared_By_ID`

```
-- SP_SETUP_ROLES_RIGHTS_GET_DATA 2
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SETUP_ROLES_RIGHTS_GET_DATA]
@Role_ID bigint
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(Select ROLE_ID from Role_Rights WHERE ROLE_ID = @Role_ID)
BEGIN
    select
    RR.Role_ID,
    RR.Form_ID,
    FR.Form_Name,
    RR.Can_View,
    RR.Can_Edit,
    RR.Can_Prepare_By,
    RR.Active,
    RR.Prepared_By_ID,
    RR.Prepared_Date
    from 
    dbo.Forms FR
    INNER JOIN dbo.Role_Rights RR
    ON RR.Form_ID = FR.ID

    WHERE RR.Role_ID = @Role_ID
    AND FR.Active = 1

    UNION 

    SELECT 
    @Role_ID AS Role_ID,
    FR.ID as Form_ID,
    FR.Form_Name,
    0 as Can_View,
    0 as Can_Edit,
    0 as Can_Prepare_By,
    0 as Active,
    NULL as Prepared_By_ID,
    NULL as Prepared_Date
    FROM 
    dbo.Forms FR
    where FR.ID not in (select Form_ID from dbo.role_rights)

END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT
    @Role_ID AS Role_ID,
    FR.ID as Form_ID,
    FR.Form_Name,
    0 as Can_View,
    0 as Can_Edit,
    0 as Can_Prepare_By,
    0 as Active,
    NULL as Prepared_By_ID,
    NULL as Prepared_Date
    FROM 
    Forms FR
END
```

END

Fig: 1
[image]

I bind the above table to Gridview and store in session. So user easily assign rights (View/Edit/etc) of specific form or multiple forms according to selected role id. Which is working fine.

**Problem**

When user edit rights and press save button below code run and in below code I put loop on Gridview Rows so each row which has been edited will save in datatable.

Code:

```
var dt = (DataTable)Session["RoleRights"];
        foreach (GridViewRow row in this.gvRoleRights.Rows)
        {
            roleID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Text);
            FormID = Convert.ToInt32(gvRoleRights.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["Form_ID"]);
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Role_ID"] = roleID;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Form_ID"] = FormID;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Can_View"] = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkView")).Checked;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Can_Edit"] = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkEdit")).Checked;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Can_Prepare_By"] = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkPrepare")).Checked;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Active"] = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkActive")).Checked;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Prepared_By_ID"] = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        }
        this.RRBO = new RoleRightsBO
        {
            SaveandUpdate = dt,
            Modified_By_ID = Context.User.Identity.Name
        };
        dt.Dispose();
        Result rst = this.RRBL.SaveandUpdate(this.RRBO);
```

The problem which I facing was in line this `dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Prepared_By_ID"] = Context.User.Identity.Name;` when loop is on column `Prepared_By_ID` and trying to save username of current login user it shows me below error

[image]

According to above error I'm trying to save string value to integer type column but as you can see in Fig 1 Datatable `Prepared By ID` column was null and in my information integer column not set to be null. So Why I'm getting this error. Also I have below code in my aspx page so Its easy for you developer to identify my mistake.

**ASPX Gridview Code**

```
<asp:GridView
    ID="gvRoleRights"
    runat="server"
    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    EmptyDataText="No Data Found!"
    ShowFooter="False"
    BorderStyle="None"
    CellPadding="3"
    GridLines="Horizontal"
    DataKeyNames="Form_ID"
    SkinID="AHGridView">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Role_ID" HeaderText="Role ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Form_Name" HeaderText="Form Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
             <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkView" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Can_View")) %>' />
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
             <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEdit" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Can_Edit")) %>' />
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Prepare">
             <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPrepare" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Can_Prepare_By")) %>' />
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active">
             <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Active")) %>' />
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Prepared_By_ID" HeaderText="Prepared By ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Prepared_Date" HeaderText="Prepared By Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: are you sure the datatype in the database for that bound field is a String.. also what you see in the datagrid for blanks could have `NULL` in the actual column value in the database.. so you will need to check for if the Prepared_By_ID is null or empty using this `string.IsNullOrEmpty` function on that value you are checking

Comment: Ok. I modified my question kindly check it now. I'm trying to save username in datatable column not in gridview column.

Comment: @MethodMan kindly check my store procedure in which I'm getting `Prepared_By_ID` column null when If data against specific role ID is not in Role Rights table.

Comment: can you run that query outside of your appliation? if so is the column empty or does it have `[Null]` in the column.. that's what I am pointing you towards.. also there is a difference between `NULL and Empty` when doing comparison of values.. if the value is NULL.. you cannot compare NULL to a string.. you can however check if the Length of that column value is > 0 to get around the Exception. are you familiar with Ternary and how to setup inline if else checks..?

Comment: I run the query in sql its shows me `NULL` in `prepared_by_id` column. and In application when I check `string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[0]["Prepared_By_ID"].ToString())` in quickwatch window it shows me `true`

Comment: if it shows true.. then you need to add that check to your condition else skip and it should check for the next row etc.. so what is the problem then

Comment: also this is not proper syntax `string.nullEmpty` so how did you check this really..?

Comment: @MethodMan Updated copy mistake.

Comment: Problem is when I updating column on every specific row by updating `prepared_by_id` with my username its shows me above error.

Comment: look at my answer.. this will do an inline check within your loop and assign string.Empty if that value in the database is Null else assign the value to the dt.Rows ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159420/discussion-between-ahmer-ali-ahsan-and-methodman).

Comment: this is very straight forward I do not have time to discuss.. I am also writing my own code .. please look at the answer if will fix your issue..

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks for your precious time. I'm trying but your solution gives the same error. If I found the another way to solve my problem I'll definitely post here.

Comment: are you familiar with Extension Methods.. you could easily create a simple one to handle this for you as well if you need to see an example on how to create and use one for your case I can do that as well..

Comment: @MethodMan Yes I know this. As I'm using 3Tier in my application I'm using it. and in my this scenario I know if I create a dummy datatable object with hard corded column names with it datatypes so I can easily solve this problem. But, what I'm actually finding the solution why I'm getting this error if my datatable column datatype is string not an integer.

Comment: look at your sql .. you set the initial colum NULL as the following 

`UNION 

    SELECT 
    @Role_ID AS Role_ID,
    FR.ID as Form_ID,
    FR.Form_Name,
    0 as Can_View,
    0 as Can_Edit,
    0 as Can_Prepare_By,
    0 as Active,
    NULL as Prepared_By_ID,`

Comment: looks like the issue is in your UNION / SELECT QUERY

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan Could you, please, provide code where you defining DataTable columns?

Comment: @fatherOfWine I'm getting result from sql as you can see I post store procedure from where I getting result set and in fig 1 I show the table which is I'm getting from SP and store as it is in session and bind with gridview.

Comment: @MethodMan +1 for identifying the issue.

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan You getting you DataTable from session. And you not initializing it after that, so by the time of the use DataTable object ALREADY created. Could you, please, show how DataTable object made it into session?

Comment: @fatherOfWine methodMan Identify the issue now I'm resolving it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: this is the same thing I was stating in my initial answer and comments about NULL values.. `Null` and `string.Empty` are not the same.. glad we could help get this solved for you quickly

Answer (score 0):

As @methodMan identify the issue is in my store procedure. I modify my store procedure and my error was gone.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SETUP_ROLES_RIGHTS_GET_DATA]
@Role_ID bigint
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(Select ROLE_ID from Role_Rights WHERE ROLE_ID = @Role_ID)
BEGIN
    select
    RR.Role_ID,
    RR.Form_ID,
    FR.Form_Name,
    RR.Can_View,
    RR.Can_Edit,
    RR.Can_Prepare_By,
    RR.Active,
    RR.Prepared_By_ID,
    RR.Prepared_Date
    from 
    dbo.Forms FR
    INNER JOIN dbo.Role_Rights RR
    ON RR.Form_ID = FR.ID

    WHERE RR.Role_ID = @Role_ID
    AND FR.Active = 1

    UNION 

    SELECT 
    @Role_ID AS Role_ID,
    FR.ID as Form_ID,
    FR.Form_Name,
    0 as Can_View,
    0 as Can_Edit,
    0 as Can_Prepare_By,
    0 as Active,
    '' as Prepared_By_ID,
    GetDate() as Prepared_Date
    FROM 
    dbo.Forms FR
    where FR.ID not in (select Form_ID from dbo.role_rights)

END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT
    @Role_ID AS Role_ID,
    FR.ID as Form_ID,
    FR.Form_Name,
    0 as Can_View,
    0 as Can_Edit,
    0 as Can_Prepare_By,
    0 as Active,
    '' as Prepared_By_ID,
    GetDate() as Prepared_Date
    FROM 
    Forms FR
END

END
```